# AS3: How to get arround the restriction of using properties (width, x, y, etc.) in static setter function?

Tags: actionscript-3, static, width, non-static

Variant 1:

```
        public static function set setWidth(w:int):void
    {
        width += (w); //not working
    }
```

.

```
        public function Caller()
    {
        ProgressLine.setWidth = -20;
    }
```

.

Variant 2

```
            public function set setWidth(w:int):void
    {
        width += (w);
    }
```

.

```
        public function Caller()
    {
        progress = new ProgressLine;
        progress.setWidth = -20;
    }
```

.

My first function (setter) is in class ProgressLine
My second function is in class Caller

How to change the width of Class ProgressLine by using static setter function (Variant 1)?

I don't want to use non-static function (Variant 2) because every time I use Variant 2 the width is back to normal. If the normal width is 200 every time I call the ProgressLine class the width is back to 200 (it renew the initial width).

Basically I want to pass the value from Caller to ProgressLine that is going to change the ProgressLine width. The problem is that I don't want to initialize the ProgressLine class every time I send the value.

Thanks you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a non-static property from a static method in the same class. Maybe you have to implement a [Singleton pattern](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html) on the class if you will only have one instance of ProgressLine.